# JPA: How to use transactions with JTA EntityManager?

Tags: java, transactions, jpa-2.0, entitymanager, jta

First of all, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049763/how-to-start-transaction-in-jta-entitymanager) solution is no option for me, because I can't change the persistence-unit.

My problem is that I use a JTA EntityManager but I need for exactly one use case something like a transaction:

```
public boolean saveWithResult(PointsValidityPeriod pointsValidityPeriod)
{
    //TODO use transaction here 
    super.save(pointsValidityPeriod);

    if (updatePrevious(pointsValidityPeriod.getValidFrom()) != 1)
    {
        logger.error("Update of Period was not possible, because UPDATE returned no single result.");

        return false;
    }

    pointsValidityPeriodEvent.fire(pointsValidityPeriod);

    return true;
}
```

**Save method (which I can't change):**

```
public void save(T entity)
{
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

You see, that there is a save invocation, but this save must be rolled back if the update went wrong, so how can I achieve that? Any ideas?

Comment: The whole point of JTA is to manage transactions. In which environment are you executingyour app? An application server with EJBs? Then use EJBs to demarcate transactions: that's their main point.

Comment: An EJB is, by default, transactional. All the code inside EJB methods is executed in a transaction by default.

Comment: I changed the method invocations. If I say `if (updatePrevious() == 2) { => don't invoke save.}` in saveWithResult method, then updatePrevious will not be rolled back, so UPDATE has been executed but INSERT (save) not, so how is this transactional? I don't understand that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution but I don't know why this works. Maybe someone could explain it to me.
In my backing bean there is the save method. There are 2 entities. getEntity() is the current entity used by the backing bean, currentValidityPeriod is another instance of that Entity which holds the latest database state of the entity, fetched by currentValidityPeriod = pointsValidityService.findCurrent(); findCurrent() is just a method which executes a TypedQuery:

```
public PointsValidityPeriod findCurrent()
{
    TypedQuery<PointsValidityPeriod> validityPeriodQuery = entityManager.createNamedQuery(PointsValidityPeriod.FindCurrent, PointsValidityPeriod.class);

    return validityPeriodQuery.getSingleResult();
}
```

This is the save method invoked by the view. As you can see, I only pass the current Entity to the service save method. In the previous Entity (currentValidityPeriod), I set another value.

```
@Override
public void save()
{       
    Date validFrom = new DateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Vienna")).toDate();
    getEntity().setValidFrom(validFrom);

    currentValidityPeriod.setValidThru(validFrom);

    pointsValidityService.save(getEntity());

    addSavedSuccessfullyMessage();
}
```

This is the service method which will be invoked:

```
@Override
public void save(PointsValidityPeriod pointsValidityPeriod)
{
    super.save(pointsValidityPeriod);
}
```

...and Superclass's save method:

```
public void save(T entity)
{
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}
```

Why does the Entity Manager persist the new Entity **and update the old one?** I just pass **ONE** Entity to the Entity Manager. Although this is the expected behavior, I'd like to know why this works.

Comment: When you're in the transaction, the JPA provider is required to synchronize the state of entity in 'managed' state with the database when the transaction commits.
So in other words - if you fetch the entity from the database while being in the transaction and you change its state, during tx commit it will automatically do `update` on this entity.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your methods transactional annotations. If you don't have any, than by default the transaction boundary is set to the business method, as pointed by JB.

So, the whole method is one transaction. Normally, the transaction management of `save` method would be important (it's a difference if it's `REQUIRED` or `REQUIRES_NEW`), but in this case you're making a local method call -- not a business method call, so any transaction management settings for `save` method doesn't apply here.

Therefore, if the `update` fails you can either base on automatic transaction rollback (if it's an EntityManager call which generates exception that rollback the Tx) or you can manually inject `SessionContext` and invoke `setRollbackOnly()` on it, something between the lines:

```
@Resource
SessionContext ctx;

public boolean saveWithResult(PointsValidityPeriod pointsValidityPeriod)
{
   // ...
    if (updatePrevious(pointsValidityPeriod.getValidFrom()) != 1)
    {
        // ...
        ctx.setRollbackOnly();
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that in this way. Eclipse shows me "No bean is eligible for injection to the injection point [JSR-299 §5.2.1]" and at the end it causes an exception while starting JBoss: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [SessionContext] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject

Comment: Shouldn't the annotation be @ Resource? See http://javahowto.blogspot.fr/2006/06/4-ways-to-get-ejbcontext-in-ejb-3.html for how to get the SessionContext from an EJB.

Comment: Ah, of course JB - `@Resource`! Sorry guys, too much CDI makes me a dull boy!